# How to split parse cloud code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I am building a mobile app using parse cloud code. I've split cloud code into several javascript file. For example,

```
- temp.js
exports.disableNote = function(id) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend('temp'));
    query.equalTo('objectId', id);
    return query.first();
}

- main.js
Parse.Cloud.define('doTemp', function(request, response) {
    temp.disableNote(request.params.id).then(function(t) {)
        response.success(true);
    });
});
```

And I get error. Please let me know how to use method from temp.js. I don't know how to return value from other file and how to use the returned value in main.js.

Comment: So what's the error? Edit your Q and add it.

Comment: I got an error in compiling iOS project. "error: use of undeclared type 'Builtin' "

Comment: Btw the code I wrote above is true?

Comment: missing "var temp = require('./temp')" ?

Comment: I already added that line